# Solspace Freeform Pro Notification Hook Bug?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I am using the freeform_module_admin_notification hook and the documentation indicates that the field contents should be available:

```
$this->fields (array) - output data of fields by fieldname
```

But the fields array contains the 'Field Label' of the field keyed by the Field Name.Not the value entered in the form by the user.

For example I have defined a text field in the admin panel for the module, 
 it is called 'name' and the Field Label is 'Name'
I have included it on a form:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-1" />
```

But the value I get within the extension is 'Name' not the value entered in the field.

$fields['name'] has a value of Name

Anyone any idea if this is a bug or I am just doing something wrong?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to look at `$variables`, not `$fields` - specifically, `$variables['field_inputs']` and/or `$variables['field_outputs']`